# SlideToggle animation skipped or not happening when div is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

In my program. I am trying to make a notification box that notifies the user about different things happening within the server. The problem is that the notification box is just directly opening instantly and closing instantly without any animation whatsoever. I have tried altering the SlideToggle speed, but that made no difference (I changed the speed to 100 milliseconds). I am thinking that the problem could lie within the fact that I am adding dynamic JavaScript elements to the div of which the animation should be acting on. Here is my code that might potentially help:

```
<div id="notification_box" class="notify">
     Notifications: 

      <button class="notification_button" id="notification_button">
             <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </button>

      <div id="notification_container" style="display: none;"></div>

</div>

<script>

var notification_box = document.getElementById("notification_box");


$(document).ready(function()
{
    //var notification_message_container = $("body").children;
    $("#notification_button").click(function()
    {
         $("#nofitication_container").slideToggle(100);
    });
}); 

 socket.on("incoming_request", function(sender))//the socket part itself is not the problem its just needed for the code to make self in this case
 {
    var incoming_request_form = make_element("div", undefined, "bg-warning");
     incoming_request_form.style.display = "inline-block";
     incoming_request_form.appendChild(make_element("p", sender + " wants to play a game with you", undefined));
     incoming_request_form.appendChild(make_element("button", "accept", "bg-success"));
     incoming_request_form.appendChild(make_element("button", "deny", "bg-danger"));
     notification_box.childNodes[3].appendChild(incoming_request_form);
 }


</script>
```

let me just explain a few small things with the code:

`notification_box.childnodes[1]` is the button

`notification_box.childnodes[3]` is the container for the incoming messages.

`notification_box.childnodes[3]` is the same as `$("#notification_container")`

Comment: I see that "nofitication_container" is misspelled in the jQuery code for `slideToggle`. Also, the socket part seems have a misplaced parenthesis: "function(sender))". Is it possible to build a [functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem you describe?

Comment: @showdev thank you, you solved the problem for me. I am really sorry for not seeing that. :)